# Prevent CKEditor from applying pasteFilter on internal and cross-editor paste operations

Tags: ckeditor

We're using CKEditor 4.5.11.  Our configuration looks like this:

```
config.allowedContent = {
     $1: {
         // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
         elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
         attributes: true,
         styles: true,
         classes: true
     }
 };
 config.pasteFilter = 'semantic-content';
```

The documentation states the following:

> Note that the paste filter is applied only to external data. There are three data sources:
>
> - copied and pasted in the same editor (internal),
> - copied from one editor and pasted into another (cross-editor),
> - coming from all other sources like websites, MS Word, etc. (external).

The documentation seems to describe exactly the behavior we want.  In fact, in Chrome things work as described.  However, in Internet Explorer and Firefox we've noticed that the paste filter is applied to internal and cross-editor paste operations as well (which we don't want and which seems to contradict the documentation).

NOTE: internal and cross-editor drag/drop operations seem to be working as described by the documentation.  We're only having issues with paste operations.

Is there something about our configuration that is preventing this from working as expected?  Or have we misunderstood the documentation?  Or is this a perhaps a bug?

---

**Update**:  As we dig further into this issue with **Internet Explorer**, we're noticing some differences based on the mark up. For example, consider the following:

```
<p><span style="color:#ff0000">one two three</span></p>
<p><font color="#ff0000">one two three</font></p>
```

In the span case, the style is lost on internal copy/paste operations when the entire span is selected.  However, if only "two three" is copied and pasted, then the style is not lost when the content is pasted (in the same editor).

In the second case, the formatting is not lost when copying and pasting (in the same editor).  Unlike in the first case, it doesn't seem to matter whether we copy/paste the entire paragraph.